# I am trying to customize the default alert function in react-native to write less code

Tags: react-native, android-alertdialog, alert, customization

> I am a beginner. I am trying to pass three parameters. The third one will be an object that will contain the actions and their text value. How can I do that?

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

    export const Calert = (title,message,[{}]) => {
    let Ctitle = title;
    let Cmessage = message;
    
        Alert.alert(
            Ctitle,
            Cmessage,
            [
              action
            ]
          )
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alert` in this way like

```
const action = [
                {text: 'OK', onPress: () => alert('OK')},  
                {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => alert('Cancel')}, 
              ] 

Alert.alert('Title', 'Message', action);
```